# Share ASP.Net web application authentication with another web sites

Tags: asp.net

I have an large ASP.Net web application that will have a large number of users and I want to make this site accessible from other sites by take the credentials uses to have authentication to other sites on another domains, to make it easy to understand from you the idea like this site we can access it by using Yahoo, Google or Facebook account

my web application use form authentications.

any Idea to do this

Thanks all

Comment: You will need to make use of Authentication API of these websites to do so. Or else you can make use of any third-party authentication API

Comment: Can you send me some of these third-party to check if can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to find out the links which might help you in your course to support multi-website authentication :-

[Facebook Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

[Google Authentication](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForWebApps.html)

[OpenId](http://openid.net/developers/)

Comment: Thank you, how I can use this to build my authentications ?

Comment: these links have all the information you need for integrating them on your website

Answer (score 0):

If you use the passport authentication provider instead of the forms provider on your web site this would enable authentication across domains that support this. This works if you can implement this across your domains or you're using existing sites that already support this.

Comment: I think the passport is for single sign-in for an application, is that right? so how I can use it? can you make your Idea clear please
Thanks

Comment: my understanding is once signed into passport it will work across multiple sites